# Numpy Advanced indexing n-dimensional array with n-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm having trouble understanding how indexing an n-dimensional array with an n-dimensional array works.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(25).reshape(5, 5)
index = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
a[index] = 1.0
# a is now full of 1.0
```

I would have expected to get the same as

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(25).reshape(5, 5)
index = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
a[index, index] = 1.0
# only diagonal of a is now 1.0
```

Why do I get in the first example an array of all 1.0s?
The numpy manual does not mention the case of indexing and n-dimensional array with an n-dimensional array (except for n=1).
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Cheers!

Comment: Look at `a[index]` and its shape.  You are applying `index` to the first dimension of `a`, effectively `a[index,:]`

Comment: in the first code block, you should take a look at the returned value of `a[index]` (without assignment). try with `index = np.array([[1,2],[4,3]])` and look at the result again, then you will understand what it really did.

Comment: Where in the docs do you get the idea of that indexing arrays are restricted to 1d?   The first paragraph of the `advanced` section reads: "Integer array indexing allows selection of arbitrary items in the array based on their N-dimensional index. Each integer array represents a number of indexes into that dimension."

Comment: The key point when using several indexing arrays is that they are broadcast against each other.  That's happening in your second `[index,index]` case.  But in the first `[index,:]` case you only have one array.  It can be multidimensional. Using a (2,5) array to index the first dimension of a (5,5) produces a (2,5,5) result.

Comment: Alright that explains it for me. It's being broadcast with [index, :]. Still seems weird tough that numpy allows this. Because index in the first case is a 2 dimensional array and it's being reshaped to a 1d array implicitly.